# REST API: An enquiry about the IDs

Tags: rest, restful-url

In RESTful APIs, for IDs in a query URL, does it have to be a numerical ID?

Can I have something like GET '/users/10gpmGBE6b' instead of GET '/users/1'? The first random string is also a unique identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be a String. As long as it is unique and it helps you to identify the underlying resource, it can be whatever you want.

It is often a good choice to provide both options. Let's say you got an API for persons, you could

`GET /users/133/` and `GET /users/jondoe` point to the same resource.